# React html customizable styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

How do they do this? I use **React.JS and hooks** and have online ordering set up, but I wish to do a similar thing where I can style the UI depending on the restaurant.

You can see in the links before, all the online ordering layout is similar but the UI is different for each one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These look like templates to me. You will need some kind of Admin interface from where a user can select the template, as well as information like brand, logo, menu for his website.

Think of something like WordPress, where we select or install a theme for our website and then set up the rest of the website by adding logo, items etc.

So you will definitely need a backend for this to store these values for the individual customers into the database.

You will also need to store the domain name mapped to each template somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I understand that part. But how do I like give them the option to customize everything up until the color and font of the button. Do I need to someone inject a different css for every restaurant. I am using react and hooks.

Comment: Each template will have its own CSS, once they select which template they want for their website, the respective CSS will load with that template.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer from @vaibhavmande. That is in fact how we do it. (I'm the mobi2go CTO). Here's another sample : https://ghostytoasty.mobi2go.com/. At a basic level you can customize your theme and layout, but you can also customize CSS for each brand. On top of that we actually have a fairly comprehensive javascript framework so orders can be added to a basket without a roundtrip to the server. In some complicated cases we have custom javascript as well (this gives great power but can leave you open to certain bugs). Lots of snapshot testing with https://www.cypress.io/ helps. We're a proud NZ based company but have offices in Australia, North America and Europe. We're also hiring so if you want to learn it all first hand : https://mobi.bamboohr.com/jobs :)